# Locating Data Within a Partition

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I inherited an instance of Azure SQL Data Warehouse.  Within SQLDW, there is a table which is partitioned on a date column.

I'm looking to archive off 2016 data by switching partitions to another table.  But I can't seem to determine which partitions hold 2016 data.

I've run the following query, which tells me how many partitions are associated with the table, but I can't figure out which partitions hold 2016 data.

```
SELECT sch.name, 
    tbl.name, 
    idx.name,
    part.*
FROM sys.schemas sch
    INNER JOIN sys.tables tbl ON sch.schema_id = tbl.schema_id
    INNER JOIN sys.partitions part ON tbl.object_id = part.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.indexes idx ON part.object_id = idx.object_id AND part.index_id = part.index_id
WHERE sch.name = 'myschema' AND
    tbl.name = 'mytable'
```

How can I determine which partitions hold 2016 data?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is Azure SQL Data warehouse I assume your table has a clustered colmnstore index.
In that case you can use pdw_nodes_column_store_segments to find the partition.
Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @object int
SET @object = OBJECT_ID('YourTable')

SELECT Object_name(p.object_id) as TableName, p.partition_number, 
c.name,
min_data_id, max_data_id, segment_id, s.row_count
FROM [sys].[pdw_nodes_column_store_segments] s
INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p   
    ON s.hobt_id = p.hobt_id 
JOIN sys.columns c
ON c.object_id =p.object_id
AND c.column_id = s.column_id
WHERE p.object_id = @object    ORDER BY p.partition_number, s.column_id, segment_id; 
GO
```

Comment: I went a different route.  Rather that using pdw_nodes_column_store_segments, I used sys.data_spaces, sys.partition_schemes, sys.partition_functions and sys.partition_range_values.  

Is there a benefit to using pdw_nodes_column_store_segments?